# What does "have all" means? Is it a collocation?

Tags: british-english, translation

Examples:

> 1. We **have all** said that we advocate effective multilateralism.
> 2. The coaches **have all** necessary documentation for domestic and
>      international passenger transport.

What is the difference in translation approaches (in Russian)? In the first example, we have **Subject + have all + Past Simple verb**, right?

Comment: "all" can be determiner, pronoun, adjective, adverb .... you may want to check a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of your sentences, **all** is modifying a noun in the sentence and is not really connected to **have**. This is not a specific verb construction. The word **all** is being used to show that every person or every thing is in agreement.

---

> We have all said that we advocate effective multilateralism.

**All** is used here to show that every person in that group has made a statement. It could be worded differently:

> We all have said...
>
> All of us have said...
>
> Each of us has said...

---

> The coaches have all necessary documentation for domestic and international passenger transport.

**All** is used here to show that the coaches possess everything that they need. Do they have the necessary documentation? Yes, they have all of it.

Answer (score 1):

The uses of 'have all' in the two sentences are quite different. In the first sentence 'all' qualifies 'we' and implies the 'we' encompasses all the relevant people and that they have said whatever. It is part of the subject of the sentence. It could have been written "We all have ...".

In the second sentence 'all' does not qualify the subject of the sentence (namely 'the coaches') but its object, namely 'necessary documentation'.

It is in a way a coincidence that these completely different functions of 'all' are potentially confused by that word following 'have' in each example.